# Unable to get key events working with angular-tree-component

Tags: angular, typescript, treeview

I have a custom typeahead component that filters an angular-component-tree. The filtering works well. However, I'm unable to get the smooth keyboard transitions like all nice typeaheads have where the first match selects and allows a user to key up and down (and TAB or Shift+Tab to/from). Any ideas what's wrong in my plunkr?

https://plnkr.co/edit/DJkM4W3fSeSFgYFLkakm?p=preview

```
@see src/app-child-component.ts
```

https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/action-mapping

Like if I start typing "C"..there's no way to arrow down to "Cases" or get back to input if I tab. Thanks in advance for any help.